# Test Material UI Tabs and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm having problems to test Material UI Tabs with Enzyme and Jest.
The problem is simulating the click on Tab component

I already tried with material shallow method (createShallow) and shallow of enzyme but the results are the same

My console.log on Tab component is returning my target element:

```
   <WithStyles(Tab) label="Tab one" />
```

Here is my code:

```
const setup = (newProps) => {
  const props = {
    selected: 0,
    changeTab: jest.fn(),
    ...newProps
  }

  const wrapper = shallowUntilTarget(<DashboardTabs { ...props } />, Base)

  return {
    props,
    wrapper
  }
}
```

The shallowUntilTarget is just a code snip to find the component recursively with .dive inside a HOC
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/539

```
it('Should call the onChange function', () => {
    const { wrapper, props } = setup()
    const tab = wrapper.find({ label: 'Tab One' })
    tab.simulate('click')
    wrapper.update()
    console.log(wrapper.debug()) // I should see a differente content after click in this tab 

    expect(props.changeTab.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) // the mock function call return 0 on the length
  })
```

And nothing happens :(

Comment: What error do you get on while running test?

Comment: and where are you making a shallow render of your comp ?

Comment: Doest not return any errors, I just don't get the expected behavior after simulate the click. And the shallow is inside a it function of jest

Comment: please show your written test

Comment: I edit my post and put the entire "it" function

Comment: show your `setup` too

Comment: There's something wrong with setup and what command you run for test?

Comment: Let me do something for you

Comment: Edit again. I'm running with the default of create-react-app: "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WrappedComponent` to dive into HOCs on components:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';


wrapper = shallow(<DashboardTabs .WrappedComponent {...props} />).dive();
```

**or**

You can find an element like this:

```
wrapper.find(‘withStyles(Tab)’)
```

Maybe it requires a little tweaks according to your use case. But it would help you

Comment: I could not make it work... I think that the HOC is working well because I could see the elements in the console with .debug() method :/

Comment: @GabrielSantos  see the Edited answer to find elements with withStyles

Comment: The find like this works fine too, but the 'simulate' click are not triggered as well

Comment: But you should send a mock function for click handler

Comment: Yes, I'm sending the mock function with the Jest helper jest.fn()

Comment: If you can add your actual component as well this would be great

Comment: I think that I figure out what was happening... I'm using the "withHandlers" of recompose and with that, this problem ocours. I test passing another function by props and works fine. I decide to test this component exporting it separately (without the HOCs) do you think that this is worth? Thank you very much for your help!